# How to release memory occupied by GMSPlacePickerViewController when I selecting different positions?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm facing issue related to GMSPlacePickerViewController where I was trying to select location for multiple times using GMSPlacePickerViewController provided by google. After several attempt I'm going to receive memory warning with 'The network connection was lost.' alert. 
 So any one knows how can I fix such issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please type this code in didReceiveMemoryWarning() method

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
    URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0
    self.viewMap.clear()
    self.viewMap.reloadInputViews()

}
```

Comment: When I clear mapview then only memory falls down, not by removing cache. Can you please explain me why this is happening?
Thanks